# SQL not working properly

Tags: mysql

i have this query but this shows column does not exist

```
SELECT 
p.content,
(select count(*) from share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share) as allow 
FROM posts p WHERE allow >="1"
```

and i got this error

Unknown column 'allow' in 'where clause'

**EDIT:**
This edit has been done to improve sql query for my use

```
SELECT 
p.content,
CASE share_type 
WHEN 'public' then "1"
when 'lsit' then 
    (select count(*) from share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share)
end as allow
FROM posts p WHERE allow=>1
```

**Error code 1064, SQL state 42000**

Comment: there is no field with name allow but i want to check allow that i have created with select query in where clause

Comment: instead of WHERE use `HAVING allow>=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use **column aliases** in `WHERE` clause.

You can, however, use `HAVING` clause instead, there you can use aliases. Difference being that `WHERE` is performed while constructing resultset, and `HAVING` is applied after the whole set is matched (which means in general, that `HAVING` is heavier).

```
SELECT 
p.content,
(select count(*) from share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share) as allow 
FROM posts p
HAVING allow >= 1
```

EDIT: Your second query should look like this:

```
SELECT p.content,
  CASE
    WHEN share_type='public' THEN "1"
    WHEN share_type='list' THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share)
    END AS `allow`
FROM posts p
HAVING `allow` >= 1
```

Comment: @FahimParkar actually, `"1"` will be treated as a number by mysql (query optimizer will deal with it)

Comment: @FahimParkar `mysql> select "1" + "1";` => `2`

Comment: P.S. when using `CASE` you should include `ELSE` case, to provide value when nothing matched before... eg `CASE WHEN cond1 THEN res1 WHEN cond2 THEN res2 ELSE res3 END`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
SELECT p.content,
    (select count(*) 
     from share_member 
     WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share) as allow 
FROM posts p 
WHERE (select count(*) 
      from share_member 
      WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share) >=1
```

or

```
(select count(*) 
 from share_member 
 WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=share)
```

should be from clause, as another result set

Comment: try something like this    SELECT s.id, cid.id FROM salerecord s, (SELECT c.id FROM customer c) AS cid
WHERE cid.id > 1

Comment: This is your improved query    SELECT p.content, allow.cnt    
FROM posts p , (SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
     FROM share_member 
     WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id=SHARE) AS allow 
WHERE allow.cnt > 1

Answer (score 0):

Your query modified as

```
SELECT 
p.content,
(select count(*) from share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id='share') as allow 
FROM posts p WHERE allow >=1
```

### Or

```
SELECT 
p.content,
(select count(*) from share_member WHERE username='pratik' AND share_id='share') as allow 
FROM posts p WHERE allow >='1'
```